# catkin_make: cannot find 'std_msg'

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm still in the process of setting up my ROS, I am getting an error message when i run this command

```
catkin_make
```

The above command is at step 4 [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage)

Then i get this error Message:

```
Base path: /home/dayo/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/dayo/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.8
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "std_msg" with any
  of the following names:
    std_msgConfig.cmake
    std_msg-config.cmake
  Add the installation prefix of "std_msg" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "std_msg_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "std_msg" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
-- Could not find the required component 'std_msg'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "std_msg" with any
  of the following names:
    std_msgConfig.cmake
    std_msg-config.cmake
  Add the installation prefix of "std_msg" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "std_msg_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "std_msg" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/dayo/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/dayo/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:290: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed*
```

This is the CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)  

catkin_package()

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

This is the Package.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>beginner_tutorials</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The beginner_tutorials package</description>
  <maintainer email="dayo@todo.todo">dayo</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>

  <export>
  </export>
</package>
```

These are the outputs of the following commands:

*dpkg -l | grep std-msgs*

```
ii  ros-kinetic-std-msgs                         0.5.11-0xenial-20171104-175741-0800                   amd64        Standard ROS Messages including common message types representing primitive data types and other basic message constructs, such as multiarrays.
```

*rospack find std_msgs*

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/std_msgs
```

*ls -al /opt/ros/kinetic/share/std_msgs*

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Feb  7 18:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 234 root root 12288 Feb  7 18:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  7 18:29 cmake
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  7 18:29 msg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1005 Feb 15  2017 package.xml
```

*which gcc*

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

new output for catkin_make :

```
Base path: /home/dayo/test_ws
Source space: /home/dayo/test_ws/src
Build space: /home/dayo/test_ws/build
Devel space: /home/dayo/test_ws/devel
Install space: /home/dayo/test_ws/install
Creating symlink "/home/dayo/test_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/dayo/test_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/dayo/test_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/dayo/test_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/dayo/test_ws/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/dayo/test_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.12") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/dayo/test_ws/build/test_results
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.8
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dayo/test_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/dayo/test_ws/build"
####
```

Output of :  *ls -al /home/dayo/catkin_ws*

```
total 28
drwxrwxr-x  6 dayo dayo 4096 Feb  8 14:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 dayo dayo 4096 Feb 10 12:10 ..
drwxrwxr-x  4 dayo dayo 4096 Feb 10 02:57 beginner_tutorials
drwxrwxr-x  8 dayo dayo 4096 Feb  8 19:16 build
-rw-rw-r--  1 dayo dayo   98 Feb  7 19:52 .catkin_workspace
drwxrwxr-x  3 dayo dayo 4096 Feb  8 19:16 devel
drwxrwxr-x  3 dayo dayo 4096 Feb  8 13:06 src
```

Output of: ls *-al /home/dayo/catkin_ws/src*

```
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 dayo dayo 4096 Feb  8 13:06 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 dayo dayo 4096 Feb  8 14:12 ..
drwxrwxr-x 4 dayo dayo 4096 Feb  8 13:06 beginner_tutorials
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dayo dayo   50 Feb  7 19:51 CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
```

new output of *Catkin_make* after deleting beginner_tutorial directory

```
Base path: /home/dayo/test_ws
Source space: /home/dayo/test_ws/src
Build space: /home/dayo/test_ws/build
Devel space: /home/dayo/test_ws/devel
Install space: /home/dayo/test_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/dayo/test_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/dayo/test_ws/build"
####
```

updated output of catkin_make after deleting beginner_tutorial folder in src

```
Base path: /home/dayo/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/dayo/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/dayo/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/dayo/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/dayo/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.8
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/dayo/catkin_ws/build"
####
```

output after deleting build, devel and install:

```
Base path: /home/dayo/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/dayo/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/dayo/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/dayo/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/dayo/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.12") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.8
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dayo/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/dayo/catkin_ws/build"
####
```

Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282147/catkin_make:-cannot-find-%27std_msg%27/) by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-02-08**:
#q208679 has the same error message, they were able to debug it with additional catkin output and contents of the package CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-08**:
Please update your question with the entire terminal output. There isn't enough information to figure out what's going on here.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-08**:
Can you post your `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt`?

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-08**:
i've updated the terminal output, pls check it out

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-08**:
please check the package.xml and CMakeLists.text

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-08**:
Can you please copy and paste those files again using the *preformatted text* (`101010`) button? The current formatting makes the contents of those files are unreadable. And please remove any comments to shorten the length of them too.

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-08**:
i have done that

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-08**:
It looks the same

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-08**:
i reposted the question while trying to effect the change you suggested but its still the same, maybe there is something i'm not getting. i'm new here. what else can i do

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-08**:
See #q270918 for how to use the preformatted text button

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-08**:
it says the page has been deleted

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-08**:
Sorry, #q270916

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-08**:
ok so i tried the post here but it was not working so i reposted the question and it is better. Please check for it

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-08**:
Please don't create a new question just to format your text. Open your `CMakeLists.txt`, copy the text, paste it into the editor here, then highlight the text, then click the *preformatted text* (`101010`) button. Then do the same with your `package.xml` file.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-09**:
I've fixed the formatting of the `CMakeLists.txt`, but the `package.xml` is a wall of text.

@dayogeorge: please copy-paste your `package.xml` again into your question, select the text you just pasted, and click on the *Preformattext Text* button (or use `ctrl+k`).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-09**:
@dayogeorge: how did you install ROS?

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "std_msg" [..]
```

`std_msgs` is part of the core of ROS. It would be really strange for it not to be installed.

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-02-09**:
@dayogeorge may you try one trick because that help for me always , save your CMakeList.txt file first then go to your Src directory delete your CMakeList.txt and then use Catkin_make it will help you

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-09**:
@dayogeorge I removed the comments in your `CMakeLists.txt` file so that it's shorter but your `package.xml` file is still unreadable. Can you please copy and paste it again? This time please make sure that it's readable (properly indented, etc.).

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-09**:
thanks guys.
Please check the package,xml now.
So how should I proceed? I'm still at step 4 on this page: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-09**:
@dayogeorge How did you install ROS? Like @gvdhoorn said, `std_msgs` should have been installed with ROS.

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-09**:
i followed the steps on ros.org
what do you suggest i do?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-09**:
What steps? We don't know what platform you are using.

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-10**:
i'm trying to installing kinetic on ubuntu.
Amd i'm following the steps [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
Can you tell us the exact command you used to install ROS?

And please link to all tutorials you followed for the installation.

Reason we keep asking about this is that `std_msgs` should definitely be there, and we're trying to make sure it's not an installation issue before checking other things.

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-10**:
i used this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

And it can be found[here](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu)

I basically just followed all the step highlighted in the link above

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
Ok. Please do this:

1. open a new terminal
2. `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`
3. `dpkg -l | grep std-msgs`
4. `rospack find std_msgs`
5. `ls -al /opt/ros/kinetic/share/std_msgs`

add the output of the last three commands to your OP (edit it).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
Also: what is the output of `which gcc`?

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-10**:
Please check my edited post for the output of the commands above

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
That all looks ok. But there is something strange looking at the `catkin_make` output that you included in your OP: I don't see any mention of compilers or `pthread`. Even with an empty workspace `catkin_make` prints lines about that for me.

Can you remove any `source ...` lines from your ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
.. `.bashrc` file (if you have any), save it, and do the following:

1. open a new terminal
2. `mkdir -p $HOME/test_ws/src`
3. `cd $HOME/test_ws`
4. `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`
5. `catkin_make`

then copy-paste the whole output of `catkin_make` into your OP.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
And just making sure: your OS is `Ubuntu 16.04` or Ubuntu Xenial, correct? `lsb_release -a` shows `Ubuntu 16.04` and `xenial`?

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-10**:
yes my ubuntun is 16.04.3 LTS xenial.
pls how do i access the .bashrc file?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
It's in your home directory. Something like `gedit $HOME/.bashrc` should open it.

Look at the end. If there are lines like `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` or `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` remove them. Save, close, follow steps in previous comment.

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-10**:
thanks a lot bro.
I removed the source and then i ran the commands.
check the output of catkin_make in my edited post.
Looks like it is done right?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
I do not see any update.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
Re: new run of `catkin_make`: yes, that looks a lot better.

Can you now do:

1. `ls -al /home/dayo/catkin_ws`
2. `ls -al /home/dayo/catkin_ws/src`

and add the output to your OP?

It's good that things are now ok, but without knowing what caused the problems initially, it's hard to avoid it.

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-10**:
you mean updates in terms of std_msgs?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
No I meant that you had posted your comment "I've edited my post", but I did not see an updated post.

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-10**:
pls check for all the outputs

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-10**:
they are towards the end of my edited post

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:
ah. Please delete (`rm -r`) the `beginner_tutorials` directory in `/home/dayo/catkin_ws`.

Catkin packages should be stored *only* in the [source space](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces#Source_Space) of your workspace. Not in the root.

After you've removed it, try `catkin_make` again.

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-10**:
please i didnt get your last message...you men i should delete the beginner_tutorials file in this directory /home/dayo/catkin_ws ?
what is rm -r ?

I'm sorry for the multiple questions pls.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:\

> I'm sorry for the multiple questions pls.

please stop writing 'please' everywhere. We already know that you post here because you want help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:\

> what is `rm -r` ?

that is how you delete directories in Linux on the command line ..

> you men i should delete the `beginner_tutorials` file in this directory `/home/dayo/catkin_ws`

`/home/dayo/catkin_ws/beginner_tutorials` is a *directory*, but yes, you should remove it.

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-10**:
lol,,ok ..no more please.

So check my edited post for the new catkin_make output

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-10**:\

> new output of Catkin_make after deleting beginner_tutorial directory

after deleting the `beginner_package` from the `src` space of your *old workspace*, you should probably have tried `catkin_make` with your *old* workspace, not your *new* workspace ....

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-10**:
output looks good now..check it out in my updated edited post...what do you think?
I need to understand why the beginner_tutorial was the hindrance?
Also, in the updated output, i can't see any message implying that std_msg is present.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-11**:\

> I need to understand why the beginner_tutorial was the hindrance?

exactly. That is what we're trying to do.

I'm not sure, but perhaps your `CMakeLists.txt` contained some error that caused it to fail.

In general though: package go into the *source space* (ie: `src`) of your workspace.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-11**:
One final thing to do:

1. open a new terminal
2. `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`
3. `rm -rf /home/dayo/catkin_ws/{build,devel,install}`
4. `cd /home/dayo/catkin_ws`
5. `catkin_make`

If that all still works, then you're ok.

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-11**:
check for the output, is it ok?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-11**:
That looks alright, yes.

It didn't build any packages (such as `beginner_tutorials`) though. But that is probably because `src/beginners_tutorials` is not a ROS package (yet).

I'd say you can now continue with the tutorial (or restart, because you probably need to (re)create the pkg).

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-11**:
Yes..thanks.

What is meant by the statement "source your environment"?
It is usually this command: `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`

**Comment by [Haadi_Cool](https://answers.ros.org/users/137407/haadi_cool/) on 2023-02-09**:
Can someone help me out? I have checked the CMakeLists.txt and also in package.xml, everything is same, I have also done the corrections, I am still encountering the same error, can someone please help me out too?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2023-02-21**:
@Haadi_Cool you should create a new question instead of leaving a comment on a 4 year old question. This will get you more visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To state the obvious (and answer the question): the catkin_build output refers to `std_msg` instead of `std_msgs`. The revised CMakeLists.txt and package.xml in the question are correct. It should build now.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2018-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-12**:
That would seem to be the actual answer, however, the initial `CMakeLists.txt` posted by @dayogeorge (rev7) already has this:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs )
```

so either that is the `CMakeLists.txt` of a different pkg, or @dayogeorge forgot to tell us something.

**Comment by [dayogeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/33604/dayogeorge/) on 2018-02-12**:
there is nothing more i'm not telling you..i followed the steps in the tutorials and i post the outputs

**Comment by [Teyhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/42003/teyhan/) on 2019-06-04**:
Did you find any solution for this problem? There is same problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , the  command : " catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp " creates for you two files:

1. package.xml
2. CMakeLists.txt.

The folder name is std_msgs (with an s) while the folder containing package.xml and CMakeLists.txt has std_msg (without an s) embedded inside it.

To Solve: Simply edit package.xml and CMakeLists.txt and change all std_msg to std_msgs.

Save and Done!

---

Originally posted by [Robotronics](https://answers.ros.org/users/49773/robotronics/) with karma: 21 on 2019-11-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adiManav](https://answers.ros.org/users/61179/adimanav/) on 2021-10-29**:
this solved the issue, thanks!